# a method of selecting random characters from given string

Tags: php

Can anyone help me with a solution that pulls the position and value of a random character from a given string using PHP. For example I have  a a string variable $string = 'helloworld'; and would like to randomly select a character from $string and echo the character and its position.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
$str = 'helloworld';

$randomChar = $str[rand(0, strlen($str)-1)];
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/g5xw0l24).

Comment: One more question,please. With the piece of code above how do I then get the value numerical value of my string character's position.

Comment: @kay Simply set it in a variable first before subscripting the string, i.e. `$position = rand(0, strlen($str)-1)`.

Comment: More than 10 years has passed since this comment, since then there is a function `random_int(min, max)` which generates crypto safe random values, while `rand()` is only pseudorandom.
Meaning, it should be avoided when generating IDs, because malicious parties could predict values generated by them.

Answer (score 8):

```
$string = 'helloworld'; 
$pos = rand(0,(strlen($string)-1));
echo $pos."th char is: ". $string[$pos];
```

Answer (score 4):

Since noone mentinoned any utf8 (multibyte) safe method, here is mine:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$possible="aábcdeéfghiíjklmnoóöópqrstuúüűvwxyzAÁBCDEÉFGHIÍJKLMNOÓÖŐPQRSTUÚVWXYZ";
$char=mb_substr($possible,rand(0, mb_strlen($possible) - 1),1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt-rand),

You can get the index of a random character by:

```
$charIndex = mt_rand(0, strlen($string)-1);
$char = $string[$charIndex]; // or substr($string, $charIndex, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$name = "Hello";
echo $name[rand(0,strlen(substr($name,0,strlen($name)-1)))];
```

Answer (score 0):

First choose a random number < strlen($yourchain)-1;

Then substr($yourchain,$random,$random+1);

Answer (score 0):

```
echo substr($string, rand(0, strlen($string)-1), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rand($x,$y)` function which returns a random number between `$x` and `$y` inclusive:

```
$str = 'helloworld';

// get a random index between 0 and the last valid index
$rand_pos = rand(0,strlen($str)-1);

// access the char at the random index.
$rand_chr = $str[$rand_pos];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "helloworld";
$randIndex = rand(0,strlen($str));
echo $str[$randIndex]," is at $randIndex";
```

Comment: *sob sob*, 5 answers while I was writing these 3 lines of code.

Comment: Not to mention your code has a bug. $randIndex should not exceed strlen($str)-1

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
$chars = preg_split('//', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
echo $string[array_rand($chars)];
```

Comment: Could you just use `str_split()` there, and doesn't `array_rand()` return the key, not value?

Answer (score 0):

1. find the length of the string , ($length)
2. use random  function to generate random value within that range , ($a=Random.get($length))
3. use substring function to get the value of the random position.($string.substring($a,1))

sorry  i dont know syntax for php (java \m/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'helloworld';

//generate a random position between 0 and string length ( note the -1 )
$randPos = mt_rand(0, strlen($string)-1);

echo 'Position : ' . $randPos . "\n";
echo 'Character : ' . $string[$randPos] . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

More internal overhead, but easy to read:

```
$str = 'helloworld';

$randChar = $str[array_rand(str_split($str))];
```

Comment: this method is really slow

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
$string    = 'helloworld';
$position  = rand(0, strlen($string));
$character = $string[$position-1];

echo $character . ' is placed ' . $position . ' in the following string: ' . $string;
```

---

**Output Example:**

e is placed 2 in the following string: helloworld

---

[**CodePad Demo**](http://codepad.org/ozzxK1qW)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might want to use it for the same case like mine:

I just wrote a simple SecretGenerator:

```
echo generateSecret(10);

function generateSecret($length) {
$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789&!^§\$ß";
$key = "";
for($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++){
    $key .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
}
    return $key;
}
```

Will return something like this: "6qß^0UoH7NP"

Of course, this is not a secure function, but for generating simple Hashes it's quite okay to use.