# Better way to select "real random" char from string

Tags: php, random

I'm using this to get random char from the string pool:

```
$charset=str_shuffle('./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789');
$charsetLength=strlen($charset)-1;
$chosen=$charset[rand(0,$charsetLength)];
```

The rand and str_shuffle functions produce pseudo-random results.

Is there a better way of getting a random char

Comment: Why do you feel it doesn't suffice?

Comment: As long you don't have a real random source, like radioactive decay, all you can get is pseudo-randomness. You might be interested in http://www.random.org/.

Comment: "Any one who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin." -John von Neumann

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5820/362536

Comment: Better how, exactly.  Which statisical test?  Is yout rand() seeded? How much entropy do you need? How much can you provide? One could easily do a lot of munging and end up worse than what you have there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short answer*: No, that's perfectly fine.

*Long answer*:

If you really need to generate (pseudo) random string, you may take a look at the [mcrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php) extension and use `mcrypt_create_iv()` with `/dev/urandom`, you can use the binary generated seed as is or convert it to base64 to get an ascii representation.

Note that there is no way to generate a real random number, you may just increase entropy. But in most case it would be enough...

Comment: Technically `mt_rand()` is a free improvement, if for no other reason than the minute speed increase that will be gained.

Comment: From what I read, `mt_rand()` isn't an improvement randomisation-wise, just performance. It also generates pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: Boris: What happens on Windows machines that don't have the /dev/urandom pool?

Comment: @Francisc, sadly it won't work as stated by the documentation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you say combining `str_shuffle` with `rand` is worse than just using one of them alone?

Comment: @Francisc: Combining them gives no significant increase in "randomness" - might as well use only one.

Answer (score 1):

- There is no need to both shuffle the string and pick a random index from it.  You don't get any additional randomness this way.
- For almost all purposes, `rand()` is going to be just fine, you'll never run into issues with it.  If you really cannot tolerate it, `mt_rand()` is better, as Somnath suggests.
- Alternatively, services such as [HotBits](http://www.fourmilab.ch/hotbits/) or [Random.org](http://www.random.org/) can give you access to truly-random values, at the cost of speed / limited requests.  Again, however, this is almost certainly not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Using [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt-rand),

You can get the index of a random character by:

```
$charIndex = mt_rand(0, strlen($string));
$char = $string[$charIndex]; // or substr($string, $charIndex, 1)
```

> Many random number generators of older libcs have dubious or unknown
>   characteristics and are slow. By default, PHP uses the libc random
>   number generator with the rand() function. The mt_rand() function is a
>   drop-in replacement for this. It uses a random number generator with
>   known characteristics using the »  Mersenne Twister, which will
>   produce random numbers four times faster than what the average libc
>   rand() provides.
>
> If called without the optional min, max arguments mt_rand() returns a
>   pseudo-random value between 0 and mt_getrandmax(). If you want a
>   random number between 5 and 15 (inclusive), for example, use
>   mt_rand(5, 15).

And no need to str_shuffle. mt_rand does shuffles between random numbers.

Source:

1. [a method of selecting random characters from given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311349/a-method-of-selecting-random-characters-from-given-string)
2. http://maymay.net/blog/2004/12/19/generating-random-letters-in-php/

Comment: Note: `mt_rand()` doesn't *actually* provide a """more random""" result than a recent libc `rand()` - it just gives more consistent result across platforms, and *may* be somewhat faster. Note also the caveat - "The distribution of mt_rand() return values is biased towards even numbers on 64-bit builds of PHP when max is beyond 2^32."

Comment: I have seen many posts similar to this, and I always wanted to know/ask if there was a way to record/save the generated random string to file, then check if it exists when re-executing the script? And `IF` it exists (which would be rather rare), not save to file and generate a new random sequence.

Comment: Finding random is random thing. Which can't be good, better, best. Just choose something giving random value.

Comment: @Fred, what is your concern?  You certainly could do exactly what you describe, but it's likely to not ever be an issue, if you just generate from a large enough range.  Even simpler though, generate a sha1 hash from a known unique string (appending the previous hash value is a good way to ensure uniqueness) and you'll similarly never run into trouble.  This is how, for example, Mercurial handles uniquely identifying revisions between multiple computers.

Comment: @Somnath Muluk: Uh, actually, that's incorrect. It is possible to measure how *non-random* the data is - in other words, measure how bad, worse, worst the PRNG is. See http://random.org/randomness/ for an introduction to (pseudo)randomness.

Comment: @dimo414 I was just curious, thanks. I'm basically swimming in new waters, as it were. Am not a newbie on the Web, but as far as PHP and sha1 and other types of hashing goes, is quite new to me.

Comment: @Fred, no worries, it's a reasonable question.  There's many ways to generate arbitrary, unique values (another cool one is [MongoDB's _id object](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs)) but sha1 is likely going to be easiest to implement, and it works quite well.

Comment: @Piskvor: I respect you. But PHP documentation says mt_rand() is 4 times faster than rand(). That's why I have given this solution.