# printing out 1 random letter of a word php functions

Tags: php, random, substring, strlen

i want to Use strlen(), substr(), and rand() to print a random character from my name to the screen.

```
<html>
<p>
<?php
// Use strlen(), substr(), and rand() to
// print a random character from my name to the screen.
$name = "jordi";

$length = strlen("$name");
$length = rand();
$partial = substr($lengt, 0,5);

print $name. "<br />";
print $length. "<br />";
print $partial. "<br />";
?>
</p>
</html>
```

the outcomes right now(the numbers are randomly generated ofcourse):

jordi

9286122

92861

can someone help me with this.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311349/a-method-of-selecting-random-characters-from-given-string . Also, why would you use strlen("$name")?

Comment: Your code contains a typo: `$lengt` has not been set. Why are you overwriting `$length` without using it?

Comment: its an exersise, 1 of the requirements "Create a new variable $name and store your name in it." (not my idea :S) @misiur

Comment: Oh, ok. However it's important that you should learn something from that excercise? Can you tell the diffrence between strlen($name), strlen("$name") and strlen('$name')? [Take a look here if not](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/language.types.string.php). Happy learning!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the steps using all of the functions required by your assignment -

```
$nameLength = strlen($name); // gets the length of the name
$randomNumber = rand(0, $nameLength - 1); // generates a random number no longer than the name length
$randomLetter = substr($name, $randomNumber, 1); // gets the substring of one letter based on that random number
echo($randomLetter);
```

Comment: I think it should be `rand(0, $nameLength - 1)` since the docs say that the second argument is the highest value to return.

Comment: I had just caught that @Rickkwa and made the change.

Comment: Just for reference, Jordi, check out the [PHP Docs](http://us1.php.net/echo) for `echo`, to read about how it works, with and without parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = "jordi";
$rndCharIndex = rand(0, strlen($name) - 1);  // random character index for the string
$rndChar = $name[$rndCharIndex];  // Look up the character in that random index
echo $rndChar;
```

Comment: please provide an explanation.