# Printing a random letter from your name in PHP

Tags: php

I just start to learn PHP, but I can't to make a easy problem. Can you help me and after say why my problem doesn't work? Here is the problem:

> 1. Create a new variable $name and store your name in it.
> 2. Then print a random character from your name. Use your knowledge of strlen(string), rand(min, max), and substr(string, start, length) to do this.
>
> HINT: Remember that substr() treats characters in a string as a zero-indexed array (first letter is at position zero). This means that the last character in the string will be at position length - 1.

I try but without result.

```
<html>
    <p>
    <?php
    $name = "George";
    $fl = substr($name, 0, strlen($name));
    $sl = substr($name, 0, 1);
    print rand($fl,$sl);
    ?>
    </p>
</html>
```

I think problem is at rand...I can't randomise items with id or something?I can print the $sl or $fl ..

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/rand  you're passing **STRINGS** to a function which expects **INTEGERS** as its arguments. plus, you're going about this backwards. you generate a random integer, then use that as the argument to substr to extract your random character, not extract the first/last chars of your string and try/fail to generate a random number using those characters.

Comment: Your problem is indeed rand.  You're not using it correctly.  First, get errors displayed by PHP so you see when an error occurs, what and where it is.  Second, look up the rand() function and try to understand what parameters it takes and what it returns.

Comment: Also, no need for `substr()` though that is your HW requirement: `echo $name[rand(0, strlen($name)-1)];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
<?php
$name = "George";
$nameLength = strlen($name);
$randomNumber = rand(0, $nameLength - 1);
$randomLetter = substr($name, $randomNumber, 1);
echo $randomLetter;
?>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23915981/5798798