# Laravel request digit position of an word per login session

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

It is possible in laravel to find an position from an digit in an word and make it random?

Example

```
Secret Word= haveaniceday
```

Laravel request now for example the last digit from word where `y`:

```
Whats the 12th digit from your word? Enter in text field
```

If i enter `y` and its true i redirect.

I have try it with `strpos` but they cant choose always an new digit per Session.

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a method of selecting random characters from given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311349/a-method-of-selecting-random-characters-from-given-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
//An example of session declaration
session()->put('position', 12);
session()->put('string', "haveaniceday");

//Fetch the stored data from the session
$position = session('position');
$string = session('string');

//Get the twelfthcCharacter 
$twelfthCharacter = $string[$position];
```

Read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session)